# Using pybitcointools to create keys, addresses, sign transactions, and push them out

Tags: pybitcointools

I WENT through the tutorial for pybitcointools using the command line. At the last line I am to `pushtx(tx3)` and Yet I keep getting this error :

```
raise Exception(p)
Exception: An outpoint is already spent in [37275258, 92842599]
```

THIS is the list of commands written :

```
from bitcoin import * 
>>> priv = sha256('some big long brainwallet password')
>>> priv 
'57c617d9b4e1f7af6ec97ca2ff57e94a28279a7eedd4d12a99fa11170e94f5a4'
>>> pub = privtopub(priv)
>>> pub 
'0420f34c2786b4bae593e22596631b025f3ff46e200fc1d4b52ef49bbdc2ed00b26c584b7e32523fb01be2294a1f8a5eb0cf71a203cc034ced46ea92a8df16c6e9'
>>> addr = pubtoaddr(pub)
>>> addr 
'1CQLd3bhw4EzaURHbKCwM5YZbUQfA4ReY6'
>>> h = history(addr)
>>> h
[{'output': u'4cc806bb04f730c445c60b3e0f4f44b54769a1c196ca37d8d4002135e4abd171:1', 'block_height': 262537, 'spend': u'772bebdf445d719d90d52a3029d27e90aa8f26eca8d431fc77cc487c377a89c4:1', 'value': 50000, 'address': u'1CQLd3bhw4EzaURHbKCwM5YZbUQfA4ReY6'}, {'output': u'b0aad2e5184099b20d53100a678e9bec2eab1b0710fb06930f333387492a82b3:0', 'block_height': 363957, 'spend': u'05551814576ba084a0736abd8df411061c5ea7e4ae72d334317f5504f6b331d6:0', 'value': 500000, 'address': u'1CQLd3bhw4EzaURHbKCwM5YZbUQfA4ReY6'}, {'output': u'97f7c7d8ac85e40c255f8a763b6cd9a68f3a94d2e93e8bfa08f977b92e55465e:0', 'block_height': 262537, 'spend': u'772bebdf445d719d90d52a3029d27e90aa8f26eca8d431fc77cc487c377a89c4:0', 'value': 50000, 'address': u'1CQLd3bhw4EzaURHbKCwM5YZbUQfA4ReY6'}]
>>> outs = [{'value': 9000, 'address': '16iw1MQ1sy1DtRPYw3ao1bCamoyBJtRB4t'}]
>>> tx = mktx(h,outs)
>>> tx 
'010000000371d1abe4352100d4d837ca96c1a16947b5444f0f3e0bc645c430f704bb06c84c0100000000ffffffffb3822a498733330f9306fb10071bab2eec9b8e670a10530db2994018e5d2aab00000000000ffffffff5e46552eb977f908fa8b3ee9d2943a8fa6d96c3b768a5f250ce485acd8c7f7970000000000ffffffff0128230000000000001976a9143ec6c3ed8dfc3ceabcc1cbdb0c5aef4e2d02873c88ac00000000'
>>> tx2 = sign(tx,0,priv)
>>> tx2
'010000000371d1abe4352100d4d837ca96c1a16947b5444f0f3e0bc645c430f704bb06c84c010000008a47304402207422fc91d125a40ce5a4f0e105554ade35dc89f59da1b62dfff75f66cd25f87e022072cea64cb10866042339c1ae8ea6d81478867f541086b07837774e2df652630a01410420f34c2786b4bae593e22596631b025f3ff46e200fc1d4b52ef49bbdc2ed00b26c584b7e32523fb01be2294a1f8a5eb0cf71a203cc034ced46ea92a8df16c6e9ffffffffb3822a498733330f9306fb10071bab2eec9b8e670a10530db2994018e5d2aab00000000000ffffffff5e46552eb977f908fa8b3ee9d2943a8fa6d96c3b768a5f250ce485acd8c7f7970000000000ffffffff0128230000000000001976a9143ec6c3ed8dfc3ceabcc1cbdb0c5aef4e2d02873c88ac00000000'
>>> tx3 = sign(tx2,1,priv)
>>> tx3
'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'

>>> pushtx(tx3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin/bci.py", line 304, in pushtx
    return f(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin/bci.py", line 259, in bci_pushtx
    return make_request('https://blockchain.info/pushtx', 'tx='+tx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitcoin/bci.py", line 23, in make_request
    raise Exception(p)
Exception: An outpoint is already spent in [37275258, 92842599]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Your help is much appreciated. 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the transaction you're creating.

#### UTXOs

The `history()` call retrieves all transaction outputs (TXOs) that have been "received" by the specified bitcoin address. This includes both *unspent* and *spent* TXOs. If you look at the received [transactions for this address](https://insight.bitpay.com/address/1CQLd3bhw4EzaURHbKCwM5YZbUQfA4ReY6) (the three where this address is listed on the right), you see that each one is marked with an `(S)`, meaning that all three have been spent.

Likewise, if you look at the contents of the `h` variable, each TXO object includes a `spend` key, which also indicates that each has already been spent. Your transaction is a double-spend attempt, which is why it was rejected.

You'll probably want to filter out those already-spent TXOs to create a list of *unspent* TXOs (UTXOs):

```
utxos = filter(lambda txo: 'spend' not in txo, h)
```

or you can call `unspent()` instead of `history()`.

(Of course, in this example `utxos` is now empty because there are no UTXOs.)

#### Signatures

The second issue is that your TX includes three inputs, but you only sign the first two. You'll probably want something like:

```
for i in range(len(utxos)):
    tx = sign(tx, i, priv)
```

or simply:

```
tx = signall(tx, priv)
```

---

<s>As an aside, hopefully you do realize that you've posted your private key on a public forum? Had those TXOs not yet been spent, they probably would have been taken by now....</s> edit: I just noticed that the private key came straight from pybitcointools docs, so nevermind....